# Middleman template loop

Tags: loops, middleman

I am creating a semi static site in middleman. I have created json local data. With my current setup i get ***File Not Found*** when using link_to

```
 = link_to f.name, "speakers/#{f._id}.html"
```

My url looks like

```
http://0.0.0.0:4567/speakers/53d544ea13dccbaf24521d98.html
```

speaker.yml

```
   {
    "people": [
        {
            "_id": "53d544ea13dccbaf24521d98",
            "index": 0,
            "status": false,
            "profile_pic": "https://res.cloudinary.com/upload/v140671888/duncan_jnow.jpg",
            "name": "Duncan Nieves",
            "company": "QOT",
            "position": "CFO",
            "email": "duncannieves@qot.com",
            "phone": "+33 (933) 598-3714",
            "address": "813 Franklin Avenue",
            "city": "Grantville",
            "country": "Cyprus",
            "biography": "Et reprehenderit aute adipisicing nostrud aliquip anim velit est ullamco non aliquip. Amet pariatur quis non dolor cupidatat nostrud enim sint ullamco occaecat. Reprehenderit est sint id est incididunt.\r\n",
            "registered": "2014-02-27T15:40:41 -01:00",
        }
    ]
 }
```

Then looping through the data

```
.section
  .event-speakers
    - data.speaker.people.take(12).each do |f|
      .speaker.mobile-6.tablet-3.medium-2.large-2{itemscope: '', itemtype: 'http://data-vocabulary.org/Person'}
        = link_to  "speakers/#{f._id}.html" do
          = image_tag f.profile_pic, width: '165', class: 'grayscale grayscale-fade'
        %span.speaker-name{itemprop: 'name'}
          = link_to f.name, "speakers/#{f._id}.html"
        %span.job-title{itemprop: 'title'}
          = f.position
        %span.job-company{itempro: 'affiliation'}
          = link_to f.company, "#", target: '_blank'
```

When i try to add the following i get the same results.

```
data.speaker.people.each do |f|
  proxy "/speakers/#{f[:_id]}.html", "speakers/layout.html",
        :locals => { :f => f }
end
```

I get the data but i can't figure out how to link to a single person. How do i define the template?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a dynamic page template file, in this case, `speakers/layout.html.haml` in your `source` directory.

In that file, you can use the same syntax as your index page, e.g.:

```
.speaker
  %p.speaker-name
    = f.name
  %p.job-title
    = f.position
  %p.bio
    = f.biography
```